# Django get the context object when from loader.get_template

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I have the following Django view.

```
def tmp_view(request):
    c = Context({'tmp_value': "Hello World"})
    t = loader.get_template('test.html')
    response = HttpResponse(t.render(c))
    return response
```

Now I want to test the view using the below function.

```
def test_view(self):
    response = self.client.get('/tmp/', follow=True)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    self.assertEqual(response.context['tmp_value'], "Hello World")
```

But when I run the testcase, I am getting the below error.

```
At line - self.assertEqual(response.context['tmp_value'], 'Hello World')
KeyError: 'tmp_value'
```

I am not sure why I am not able to get the context object in my test function.

Comment: Why don't you simply use the `render` shortcut instead of manually rendering the template? If you are using a different template engine than `DjangoTemplates`, [`context_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/template-response/#django.template.response.SimpleTemplateResponse.context_data) might be more suitable.

Comment: I'd second the recommendation to use `render`, or as an alternative, `TemplateResponse`, which does pretty much the same thing.

Comment: I know. But I am working with an old code base which is structured in the above way.

Comment: Can you print the contents of `response.context`?